# Can't Install Laravel OSX Catalina

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php, homebrew

After attempting to upgrade Laravel after years of successful use on older versions and after upgrading to OSX 10.15.2 (Catalina) I can no longer seem to install Laravel for cli.

```
# php -v
PHP 7.2.24 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 13:01:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

```
# composer --version
composer --version
Composer version 1.9.3 2020-02-04 12:58:49
```

```
# composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to /Users/$username/.composer
Using version ^3.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/installer v3.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.4.37
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.37
    - laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires symfony/console ^4.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.0, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.1, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.10, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.11, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.12, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.13, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.14, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.15, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.2, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.3, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.4, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.5, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.6, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.7, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.8, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.9, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.1, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.10, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.11, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.12, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.2, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.3, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.4, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.5, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.6, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.7, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.8, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.9, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.0, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.1, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.10, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.11, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.12, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.2, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.3, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.4, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.5, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.6, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.7, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.8, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.9, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.0, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.1, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.10, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.11, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.2, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.3, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.4, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.5, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.6, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.7, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.8, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.9, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.0, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.1, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.2, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.3, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.4, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.0, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.1, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.2, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.3, v3.4.37].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.4, v3.4.37].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.4.37) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.4.37].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I've spent 2 days grinding through suggestions here and elsewhere but not having any success fixing this issue.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

After a series of random attempts I finally was able to run:

```
composer global update
```

and then

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

which seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I was having this same issue, but with guzzlehttp/guzzle. it solved it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've got incompatible hard-coded dependencies in your `/Users/$username/.composer/composer.lock` file

I have also encountered this issue and it turns out that my laravel/homestead and laravel/valet was using an old version of symfony/console.

Simple fix:

```
1. composer global remove laravel/homestead
2. composer global remove laravel/valet
3. Finally, composer global install laravel/installer
```